# How do I programmatically import a class module in the Office Visual Basic editor?

Tags: vba, vbe

I can programmatically import a standard module with VBA in the Visual Basic Editor for Office like so:

```
Dim vbComp As VBComponent
Set vbComp = application.vbe.ActiveVBProject.VBComponents.Import(pathToFile)
vbComp.Name = moduleName
```

The type of the imported module is then `vbext_ct_StdModule`.

However, I'd like to import a class module (so that the type is `vbext_ct_ClassModule`) . Is there an equivalent function to achieve this?

Comment: I have no problem using your code with a class module that was properly exported as a .cls file. Comes straight into the Class Modules folder.

Comment: I tried that as well and it didn't work. Let  me try again.

Comment: I'm unclear whether you already have the `.cls` class module exported, but regardless, Ron de Bruin has [this excellent resource](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win002.htm) including everything you need for exporting & importing all module types. Read the instructions carefully since references & security settings are required. The code that actual imports will be something along the lines of `wb.VBProject.VBComponents.Import filename.cls`. See also [Chip Pearson's related page](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx) and also [this page](http://www.exceltip.com/modules-class-modules-in-vba)